# Instagram Graph API - Data access expires

Tags: instagram-graph-api

I often have the case where an data access token expires, but I still can continue to pull in content from Instagram Graph API.
I use `instagram_basic,instagram_manage_comments,instagram_manage_insights` permissions.

For which permissions data access token expiry does not apply?

The same goes for user and page access tokens.[screenshot from facebook token debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI4MP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Even I have the same query. Will I be able to use the 'insatgram_basic' and other instagram permissions, if the "Data Access Expires" gets expired? I just created an App couple of days ago and it shows Data Access Expires = 3 months, even though Expires = Never. Would be helpful if someone could answer. Thanks!
[Screenshot of Data Access Expires](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0YtH.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please refrain from asking additional questions as an answer. If you'd like to ask a new question, open a separate question and reference this question in the description. [Read more.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)